# How can I convert Linux makefile to Windows makefile

Tags: windows, makefile, fortran, gfortran

Following makefile, I am using to generate Fortran executable file in Linux now I need to generate same for windows. How can I write and run the same makefile in windows or if possible can I convert this makefile for windows makefile?

**#Makefile for Linux**

```
PROG =  sbdart

OBJS =  atms.o disort.o disutil.o drt.o params.o spectra.o \
        tauaero.o taucloud.o taugas.o

FC = f95
FFLAGS = -o -c
LDFLAGS =

LIBS =

$(PROG): $(OBJS)
    $(FC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

atms.o:  params.o atms.f

disort.o:  params.o disort.f

disutil.o:  params.o disutil.f

drt.o:  params.o tauaero.o taugas.o spectra.o drt.f

params.o:  params.f

spectra.o:  params.o spectra.f

tauaero.o:  params.o tauaero.f

taucloud.o:  params.o taucloud.f

taugas.o:  params.o taugas.f


clean:
    rm -f $(PROG) $(OBJS) *.mod
```

Comment: Your Linux Fortran compiler is apparently GCC Fortran (`gfortran`). Are you using it on Windows too?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for porting build settings across systems I know of is to create a CMakeLists.txt and generate Makefiles for both automatically using [CMake](https://cmake.org/).

You can find an example of Fortran projects with CMake [here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMakeForFortranExample).